# ¿Por qué no salen las alertas si detecta el valor de la variable?

Tags: javascript, html5, variables, alert

Acabo de terminar un borrador para un proyecto que estoy realizando y al momento de ejecutarlo no me salen las alertas de la función a pesar de que si me la detecta si pongo una alerta para que me muestre la variable.

Se basa en que tengo un rol de una empresa por lo que si ese rol es admitido me proporcione una alerta verificándolo, por lo que ahí falla a pesar de que coloque (en este caso la variable se llama cargo)

```
alert=(cargo)
```

Y me proporcione la alerta con el cargo respectivo al ejecutar la función la alerta no se ejecuta y no entiendo por que

```js
function validacion() {
  let cargo = document.getElementById('cargo').value
  if (cargo == 'ingeniero') {
    alert(" eres " + cargo)
  } else {
    if (cargo == 'jefe de planta') {
      alert(" eres " + cargo)
    } else {
      if (cargo == 'administrador') {
        alert(
          " eres " + cargo)
      } else {
        if (cargo == 'secretario') {
          alert(" eres " + cargo)
        } else {
          alert("No se ha proporcionado un cargo valido")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Empresa.inc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="container m-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-xl-9">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <p class="titulo">Acceso
              <a href=""></a> la plataforma</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <select class="form-select" id="cargo">
              <option selected>Cargo</option>
              <option value="ingeniero">Ingeniero</option>
              <option value="jefe de planta">Jefe de Planta</option>
              <option value="administrador">Administrador</option>
              <option value="secreterio">Secretario</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="validacion" onclick="validacion()" value="Ingresar">Ingresar</button></td>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! donde llamas a la funcion validacion?

Comment: Parece funcionar, todos los cargos generan su alerta.

Answer (score 1):

Veo varios detalles que podrían estar interfiriendo en la ejecución correcta,

El botón id=validacion es submit, pero no hay una etiqueta form de apertura, cambia eso por un type="button"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="validacion" onclick="validacion()" value="Ingresar">Ingresar</button>
```

Después tu función validacion() pareciera que no tenia llave de cierre, y se puede mejorar bastante agregando algo como esto

```
function validacion() {

    let cargo = document.getElementById('cargo').value;
    let puestos = ["ingeniero", "jefe de planta","administrador", "secreterio"];

    if( puestos.includes(cargo) )
        alert(" eres " + cargo)
    else
        alert("No se ha proporcionado un cargo valido")

}
```

Esto evita hacer tantos condicionales if y else. Si estás iniciando, desde ya indenta tu código lo mejor que puedas. Así tú mismo podrás identificar los errores en el.